# What is the size limit of a SOAP message's input parameter

Tags: java, soap, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

Is there a size limit on a SOAP message's input parameters?

I currently need to get a potentially large-ish string with the request, so I'm trying to decide if I will have to use SOAP attachments or not.

I am using Java Web Services.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no theoretical limit: I don't think there is anything in the specifications about maximum lengths, so this will be heavily dependent on your server. Have a look at the documentation for the server.

Obviously it depends upon what you're transmitting, but it may be easier to use attachments just to keep the thing simple. A word document encoded as a parameter may not be the most logical way to represent things.

Comment: I think you are correct. I'm pushing large strings (500K chars) through a test WS with good results. I will be transmitting plain text so I think this way will work nicely.

Thanks!