# What is the maximum size of data can be transfered through Web Service?

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, jax-ws

I am developing one application in java using JAX-WS.One of my service is for fetching data from MySql database which i am using back end.Is it possible to transfer a large amount of data(BLOB/MEDIUMBLOB) through JAX-WS response message.Is there any limitation of message size.If yes what is the maximum allowable size of message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3124271/767881

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP GET is not limited and can be even endless. There is not problem to transfer as much data as you want.

Comment: is it a very good approach to transfer .5 or 1mb data through JAX-WS...What do you suggest ? If i use soap attachment also will it create any response issue ? For my test environment its giving convening result but i don't know how it will react after deploying in server.....

Comment: @anupammaiti - Obviously, sending large amounts of data will use CPU and network bandwidth ... and could result in poor performance as a direct result.  However, you will be only be able to say if this will be a problem in production by making some estimates and doing some tests.  And given the choice, you are likely to get better performance by not sending the data at all.

Comment: 100% agree with @StephenC and would like to add that 1MB is not a too much unless you want to serve 1000 clients simultaniously.